# how to get all products from a category which have this attribute?

Tags: collection, product-list, filter, product-attribute

I have spent two days in this problem: I can´t find the right solution for getting all products which are related to a specified category and which have the searched attribute.

In my special case: We got a selector for printer colors in three steps:
1. Choose the printer brand
2. Choose the device type (laser printer, inject printer, etc.)
3. Choose the modell type

The related printer colors should be shown now. So I need to find out which they are.

I tried like this:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(1274);
$prodCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($category);
$prodCollection->addAttributeToSelect('printercolor');
$prodCollection->addAttributeToFilter('printercolor', array('eq' => $currentPrinterDescription);
```

In the two days I have many alternative solutions for doing this, but none of them worked as accepted.

Hope you guys can help me.

Edit: I solved it myself. My code looks now like this:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$prodCollection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('my_attribute');
foreach ($prodCollection as $prodAttr)
{
    $var = explode(',', $prodAttr->getData('my_attribute'));
    if ($attr = $prodAttr->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute'))
    {
          $af = $attr->getFrontend();
          $selectedOptions = $af->getSelectOptions();
                  foreach ($selectedOptions as $s)
                  {
                        $products[] = trim($s['label']);
                        // ...
                  }
    }
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Since multiselects are stored as comma separated values you can probably use a like on it.

```
$prodCollection->addAttributeToFilter('printercolor', array(
   array($currentPrinterDescription),
   array('like'=>'%,'.$currentPrinterDescription),
   array('like'=>$currentPrinterDescription.',%'),
   array('like'=>'%,'.$currentPrinterDescription.',%'),
));
```